# javascript - hierarchical JSON from JSON converted from wrapper class list in apex

Tags: javascript, json, visualforce, apex

JSON I got by serializing wrapper class list:

```
{
"tree": [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Children": ["2", "3"]
}, {
    "Id": "2",
    "Children": []
}, {
    "Id": "3",
    "Children": []
}, {
    "Id": "4",
    "Children": ["1"]
}, {
    "Id": "5",
    "Children": ["4", "6"]
}, {
    "Id": "6",
    "Children": []
}]
```

}

Formatted JSON I need in hierarchical form:

```
{
"tree": [{
    "Id": "5",
    "Children": [{
        "Id": "4",
        "Children": [{
            "Id": "1",
            "Children": [{
                "Id": "2",
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Id": "3",
                "Children": []
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "Id": "6",
        "Children": []
    }]
}]
```

}

I need to get this hierarchical form of JSON to show the tree structure on visualforce page upto nth level.

Comment: So using the Children you need to create a recursive function. This isn't a code writing service. You need to specify what you are stuck on....

Comment: I have already worked on the static part of JSON in the format, what I am trying to get. and my function is working properly up to nth level. But what am I stuck at is the format I am getting dynamically from controller

Comment: So I need to just format the JSON in hierarchical form through javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for this problem, it will format this JSON in hierarchical format.

```
function convert(array)
{

var map = {}
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    var obj = array[i]
    if(!(obj.Id in map))
    {
        map[obj.Id] = obj
        map[obj.Id].children = []
    }

    if(typeof map[obj.Id].parent == 'undefined')
    {
        map[obj.Id].Id = obj.Id
        map[obj.Id].parent= obj.parent
    }

    var parent = obj.parent || ' ';
    if(!(parent in map))
    {
        map[parent] = {}
        map[parent].children = []
    }

    map[parent].children.push(map[obj.Id])
}
return map[' ']
}
```